# SQLServerBulkCopy JDBC driver - How it works

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, mssql-jdbc

Exploring SQLServerBulkCopy JDBC from Spring Batch to copy millions of records from Azure SQL to SQL server installed on Azure VM

Source is SQL view and Destination is SQL table

Batchsize = 250k and Count of records = 20Million

Question is related to reading from source. As batch size is 250K , it is not going to read entire 20Million into memory. But wondering how it works internally

1. Is it going to make 80 calls (20Million/250K) to source database?
2. If above one is true , how is it going to keep track of records read with out providing sort key in
   the code. Sample below or i searched for other samples, no where i found sort key has to be given for
   batch size to work. Everywhere batchsize impacts on writes to destination is mentioned but not on
   reads
3. Can streaming be enabled in above SQL server to SQL server scenario?

I searched a lot finding answer for #1 , but could not find good information. Any insights is very helpful. Thanks!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You can stream the data if u use a reader, to execute the bulk copy. [Example](https://github.com/pregress/SqlServerBulkCopyTool/blob/f9da4a0f6b311a3c70903017ad71d37226c07b42/src/SqlServerBulkCopyTool/SqlServerBulkCopyTool/Program.cs#L37)

Comment: Thanks @PrebenHuybrechts. As my source table is millions , would like to fetch few records at a time using streaming. Is there any equivalent reader to stream in JAVA. Sample i found are using setFetchSize on Resultset or connection , but not sure how it keeps track of last record read and fetch from next record as sort order of records is not guaranteed while fetching records from sql table or sql views